# Proving that $\Pr[|X| > T\sqrt{n}/2] \geq \Pr[|X-\mathbb EX| < T\sqrt{n}/2]$

Tags: probability, inequality

I am reading a paper [Revealing information while preserving privacy](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~asmith/privacy598/papers/dn03.pdf) and I am stuck in a step in the proof of Lemma 4. I'll write the relevant details below so you do not need to extract them from the paper.

Let $x,d \in [0,1]^n$ be constant vectors. Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be independent random variables such that $X_i$ takes value $x_i-d_i$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ with probability $1/2$, and let $X=\sum_i X_i$. Let $T$ be a positive constant, and assume $\mathbb EX \geq T\sqrt{n}$.

The step I am stuck is:

$$
\Pr[|X| > T\sqrt{n}/2] \geqslant \Pr[|X-\mathbb EX| < T\sqrt{n}/2]
$$

This is what I have so far:

$$
\Pr\left[ \lvert X \rvert  > T\sqrt{n}/2 \right] 
 = \Pr\left[   
    T\sqrt{n}-\lvert X \rvert < T\sqrt{n}/2 \right] \\
  \geqslant \Pr\left[ \mathbb EX-\lvert X \rvert < T\sqrt{n}/2  \right] \\
 \geqslant \Pr\left[ \rvert \lvert X \rvert-\mathbb EX \rvert < T\sqrt{n}/2  \right] 
$$

I am not sure how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Pr[\vert X\vert>T\sqrt{n}/2]=\Pr[\vert X - \mathbb{E}X +\mathbb{E}X\vert>T\sqrt{n}/2]\\
\geq \Pr[-\vert X - \mathbb{E}X\vert+\vert\mathbb{E}X\vert>T\sqrt{n}/2]\\
= \Pr[\vert X - \mathbb{E}X\vert<\vert\mathbb{E}X\vert-T\sqrt{n}/2]\\
\geq \Pr[\vert X - \mathbb{E}X\vert<T\sqrt{n}-T\sqrt{n}/2=T\sqrt{n}/2]$$

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the first inequality? I don't seem to be able to know how it was deduced.

Comment: 1st inequality: Using triangle inequality, the event on the RHS is a subset of the event on the LHS, so its probability is smaller.

2nd inequality: The same as above using the assumption $\mathbb{E}X\ge T\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Yes. But isn't by using the triangle inequality we have: $|X-\mathbb EX+\mathbb EX|\leqslant|X-\mathbb EX|+|\mathbb EX|$? Where did the minus sign in $-|X-\mathbb EX|$ come from?

Comment: This should clarify: $\vert X - \mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}X\vert+\vert\mathbb{E}X -X \vert \geq \vert \mathbb{E}X\vert$. That is $\vert u+v\vert+\vert-u\vert\geq\vert v\vert$.